# Pandas single level multiindex vs plain index

Tags: python, pandas

One may produce single level MultiIndex in pandas like so:

```py
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([[1,2,3]])
index
print ('Number of levels = %d' % index.nlevels)
```

```py
MultiIndex(levels=[[1, 2, 3]],
           codes=[[0, 1, 2]])
Number of levels = 1
```

And then use it as simple index, for example in order to init DataFrame:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([0,0,15], index=index, columns=['d'])
df
```

But is there any 'special' use cases of single level multiindex instead of simple index? I mean the cases where simple index 'less comfortable' or even won't work.

Comment: I do not think they have different

Comment: I'm agree on 0.99. But I wonder is someone using 1-level MI instead of RI. Maybe when some general processing which should span MI as well as RI..?

Comment: ~sure done :-) ~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only think of the memory usage , if you only have one single level you should using plain index .

```
df.index.memory_usage()
123
df.index=[1,2,3]
df.index.memory_usage()
24
```

Comment: If talking for regular index - one may add that it is more familiar for users. And in general working with regular index is simpler than with 1-level MultiIndex.

Answer (score 0):

I think the behavior *should* be the same, but there appear to be subtle differences.

For example, the single-level MultiIndex causes problems with indexing.
See this question: [Pandas indexing error with (1) non-unique query, and (2) single-level MultiIndex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65379153/pandas-indexing-error-with-1-non-unique-query-and-2-single-level-multiindex)