# Flatten a single-leveled multiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, multi-index

Indexing into a Pandas DataFrame throws an error when:

- The query has multiple copies of the same value.
- The index in the DataFrame is a single-level MultiIndex.

The below code shows a simple example

```
import pandas as pd
# columns as str class -- works
D = pd.DataFrame([[1,2]], columns = ['A','B'], index = ['R1'])
print(D.loc[:,['A','A']], '\n')   # OK

# columns as Index class -- works
D = pd.DataFrame([[1,2]], columns = pd.Index(['A','B']), index = ['R1'])
print(D.loc[:,['A','A']], '\n')  # OK

# columns as single-level MultiIndex -- fails
D = pd.DataFrame([[1,2]], columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['A','B']]), index = ['R1'])
print(D.loc[:,['A','A']])   # error "Index._join_level on non-unique index is not implemented"
```

In the last case, `D.columns` is

```
MultiIndex([('A',),
            ('B',)],
           )
```

Why does this occur?  What is the easiest way to fix it?

In my program, I do not construct the DataFrame columns directly (as I do in the simple example above); instead, it is obtained via a drop_level command (producing the single-level MultiIndex).  So, simply creating a DataFrame using Index class is not an option.

Comment: @cs95 it arises from a "drop_level" operation.  Specifically, to broadcast index of small to large DataFrame  (sorry, copy-paste kills line-break)


# Requires: levels with names match
def broadcast(dfSm, dfBig):
    # drop levels not in names
    def get_level_subset(midx, names):
        return midx.droplevel(midx.names.difference(names))
        
    #
    chop = [get_level_subset(dfBig.axes[i], dfSm.axes[i].names) for i in [0,1]]
    return pd.DataFrame(dfSm.loc[chop[0], chop[1]].values,
                        index = dfBig.index, columns = dfBig.columns)

Comment: You can fix the single level multiIndex issue by flattening your index:

    `D.columns = D.columns.get_level_values(0)`